# Subtract variable from date in jquery (countdown style)

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I find the difference between today's date and a future date, eg:`2014/12/31`, in JQuery so that I can display the days, hours, minutes and seconds left **per second** in HTML classed div tags?

The HTML would look like this:

```
<div id="hours">00</div>
<div id="days">00</div>
<div id="minutes">00</div>
<div id="seconds">00</div>
```

Like a countdown timer.

Comment: There are *so many* duplicates of this question that it's hard to pick the best one. Did you look through all of those and find nothing?

Comment: Check http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html or http://trulycode.com/bytes/easy-countdown-to-date-with-javascript-jquery/

Comment: @Pointy, I only checked pluggins, I want an idea of how to build the app myself. Did you even read through the others? Did you read through mine?

Comment: @lolka_bolka, thanks, fantastic link, will definitely have a look! Will update

Comment: @proPhet of *course* I read through your question; it's only a few lines long. There are dozens of other questions on the same topic. Have you, for example, read through [the documentation for the Date API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FDate)?

Comment: @Pointy, yes indeed, definitely good information there! My question, though, is how to **find the difference** from the values obtained using the methods and processes delineated in your reference.

Comment: lol, I swear if I come to an acceptable answer first I will assume your reputation is wasted... #pompus?

Comment: It may in fact be a combination of comments by Pointy and lolka_bolka that will support the production of an answer to this question.

Comment: Old questions: [1968167](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968167) [3224834](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834) [41948](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41948) [13894632](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894632) [14612919](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612919) - there are many more.

Comment: @Pointy, thanks! those links helped a lot! I must not have looked around thoroughly enough.

Answer (score 1):

Take [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) it is really easy for tasks like this.

```
var a = moment([2007, 0, 29]);
var b = moment([2007, 0, 28]);
a.diff(b, 'days') // 1
```

Comment: thanks alot man! As per my comments, however, I need advice on how to build this manually.